# Problem in handling image logic in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-development

I'm still learning Flutter.

I made an app that has default fruits list with AssetImage(), and the ability for the user to add images to it with image_picker.

The problem I encountered is that when I edit the item's title or description and keep the image unchanged the image thumbnail in the list changed to the default "no_image" and didn't keep the original image. Then when I'm trying to edit again, I encountered null check operator used on a null value.

Here's the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:training/logics.dart';
import '../models/images_instance.dart';

class AddEditImageData extends StatefulWidget {
  final int? index;

  const AddEditImageData({super.key, this.index});

  @override
  State<AddEditImageData> createState() => _AddEditImageDataState();
}

class _AddEditImageDataState extends State<AddEditImageData> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  Widget buildAvatar() {
    ImageProvider<Object>? imageProvider;

    if (selectedFileImage != null) {
      // Use selectedFileImage if available
      imageProvider = FileImage(selectedFileImage!);
    } else if (widget.index != null && widget.index! >= 0 && widget.index! < imagesInstances.length) {
      // Use AssetImage if index is valid
      imageProvider = AssetImage(imagesInstances[widget.index!].imageString!);
    } else {
      // Handle the case where neither selectedFileImage nor widget.index is available
      imageProvider = const AssetImage('assets/images/no_image.png');
    }

    return SizedBox(
      width: 120,
      height: 120,
      child: CircleAvatar(
        radius: 50,
        backgroundImage: imageProvider,
      ),
    );
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.index != null) {
      // Populate fields with existing data for editing
      final imageInstance = imagesInstances[widget.index!];
      imageTitleController.text = imageInstance.imageTitle ?? '';
      imageDescriptionController.text = imageInstance.imageDescription ?? '';
      selectedFileImage = imageInstance.imageFile;
    }
  }

  void resetFields() {
    imageTitleController.clear();
    imageDescriptionController.clear();
    selectedFileImage = null;
  }

  void navigateBack() {
    Navigator.pop(context); // Navigate back after saving
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          // The title text which will be shown on the action bar
          title: Text((widget.index != null) ? 'Edit Image' : 'Add New Image'),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const Text('Add Image Data'),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    const Text('Add Image'),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            pickImage(ImageSource.gallery).then((pickedImage) {
                              if (pickedImage != null) {
                                setState(() {});
                              }
                            });
                          },
                          child: const Text('From Gallery'),
                        ),
                        ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            pickImage(ImageSource.camera).then((pickedImage) {
                              if (pickedImage != null) {
                                setState(() {});
                              }
                            });
                          },
                          child: const Text('From Camera'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),

                    buildAvatar(),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    const Text('Add Image Title'),
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: imageTitleController,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    const Text('Add Image Description'),
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: imageDescriptionController,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (widget.index != null) {
                      saveEditedItem(widget.index!);
                    } else {
                      addImageInstance(context);
                    }

                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  child: Text((widget.index != null)
                      ? 'Submit Edited Image Instance'
                      : 'Submit New Image Instance'))
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

I aim to be able to add, edit and delete images, and / or title and / or description, whether it is on default item which has image of type "AssetImage", or on a newly added item to the list which has image of type "File".

Hope someone help fixing this issue

Answer (score -1):

I have checked your code, @Ahmad Loutfy. Please review the following steps, as they should prove helpful.

- During the editing process, it is mandatory to update `selectedFileImage` especially in case a new image has been selected.
- Within the `buildAvatar()` function, ensure that `selectedFileImage` must be null, AssetImage is employed as an option in line with the default "no_image".

Comment: Can you give a code for this?

Comment: @Ahmed Loutfy Please replace below code in your `intiState()` with last line 

// Only update selectedFileImage if a new image is selected
    if (selectedFileImage == null) {
      selectedFileImage = imageInstance.imageFile;
    }

Hope this help!

Comment: Ok, I will try it after returning home from work

Comment: Unfortunately, when i edited the item title and description while keeping image unchanged, it also displaying "no_image"

Comment: Could you kindly share your entire code? This would greatly assist me in offering a precise solution for your issue.

Comment: Here's the repo: https://github.com/ahmloutfy/training_app

Comment: Kindly share your Flutter version. You can find it by navigating to Android Studio, then selecting File > Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Flutter.

Comment: my flutter version is 3.13.6